# myVar = !!someOtherVar

Tags: javascript, variables

Can I get some clarification on why I would want to use this?

```
myVar = !!someOtherVar;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to pass a boolean value to a function, or are anal about evaluating only booleans in conditional statements, that casts `someOtherVar` to a boolean for you by double-negating it.

Answer (score 12):

In non-strictly typed languages, the ! operator converts a value to a boolean. Doing it twice would be equivalent to saying

```
myVar = (boolean)someOtherVar
```

Note that this is not recommended for code clarity.

Comment: ... or is it not not unrecommended?

Comment: @STW: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0QOya9-lwQk (see 1:44 and 8:38)

Comment: You can type cast in JS using `Boolean(someOtherVar)`

Comment: @BoltClock -- by the first minute I was having flashbacks to the South Park where Butters becomes a pimp; you know what I'm sayin?

Comment: @MooGoo -- thanks for my "how didn't I know that exists?" moment of the day

Comment: @MooGoo that is **not** a "type cast" - that's an object construction, and not the same thing at all.

Comment: @Pointy: in which situations does the difference between `Boolean()` and `!!` matter?

Comment: @chlmertz, @MooGoo - you're right; when the `Boolean()` constructor is *called* (as opposed to being invoked with `new`), it seems to return either `true` or `false` - in other words, the constants, and not an object.  Thus `true === Boolean(2)` is `true`, while `true === new Boolean(2)` is `false`.  The MDC page pretty much says exactly this (and leaves one wondering just what use the objects might be).

Comment: @chimetz, @MooGoo I personally still wouldn't use the term "type cast", but I guess that's just a matter of preference.

Comment: It creates a bona-fide object that wraps the primitive value. As far as uses go, there's not many. You can add properties to the object (whereas with a primitive any added properties would be ignored), but it is useless in comparisons, because objects are only == to themselves in JS. I would say "type cast" is appropriate because it describes the behavior exactly, even if the implementation here is different than in most other languages (calling a function that returns a value vs special syntax)

Answer (score 7):

*(Rewritten to clarify, simplify)*

That statement performs a couple different actions:

```
myVar = // This portion is a regular assignment, it will store the value of the suffix
        !!someOtherVar; // This portion is evaluated to a boolean result
```

The `!!someOtherVar`, I assume, is what you're really asking about.  The answer is simple: it performs two logical NOT operations against the [truthiness](http://11heavens.com/falsy-and-truthy-in-javascript) (a Javascript'ism) of `someOtherVar`.

In other words, if you understand the `!` operator, this just combines two of them (`!!` isn't a different operator).  By doing this it essentially returns the boolean evaluation of `someOtherVar`--in other words, it's a cast from whatever type `someOtherVar` is to `boolean`.

So... to walk through this, and pay attention to the result of `myVar`:

```
myVar = someOtherVar; // myVar will be whatever type someOtherVar is
myVar = !someOtherVar; // myVar will *always be boolean, but the inverse of someOtherVar's truthiness
myVar = !!someOtherVar; // myVar will *always be boolean, and be the equivalent of someOtherVar's truthiness
```

Answer (score 7):

It's a double negation, but it also works for type casting. `!somevar` will return a boolean (true, if somevar is "falsey" and false if it is "truthy", as per [Crockford's lectures](http://www.protonfish.com/jslang.shtml)). So, `!!somevar` will be `not(bool)` and hence it will be boolean.