# What does a !! in JavaScript mean?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [myVar = !!someOtherVar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772552/myvar-someothervar)
>   [What does the !! operator (double exclamation point) mean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406604/what-does-the-operator-double-exclamation-point-mean-in-javascript)

Came across this line of code

```
strict = !!argStrict
```

... [here](http://github.com/kvz/phpjs/raw/master/functions/array/in_array.js) and wondered what effect the `!!` has on the line? Pretty new to JS!

Comment: We need a Javascript version of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php-closed!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It converts your value to a boolean type:

```
var x = '1';
var y = !!x;

// (typeof y === 'boolean')
```

Also note the following:

```
var x = 0;
var y = '0';       // non empty string is truthy
var z = '';

console.log(!!x);  // false
console.log(!!y);  // true
console.log(!!z);  // false
```

Answer (score 4):

It converts the value to a value of the boolean type by negating it twice. It's used when you want to make sure that a value is a boolean value, and not a value of another type.

In JS everything that deals with booleans accepts values of other types, and some can even return non-booleans (for instance, `||` and `&&`). `!` however always returns a boolean value so it can be used to convert things to boolean.

Answer (score 2):

It is a pair of [logical not operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators).

It converts a falsey value (such as `0` or `false`) to `true` and then `false` and a truthy value (such as `true` or `"hello"`) to `false` and then `true`.

The net result is you get a boolean version of whatever the value is.

Answer (score 1):

It converts to boolean

Answer (score 0):

Its a "not not" arg

commonly used to convert (shortcut) string values to bool

like this..

if(!!'true') { alert('its true')}

Comment: `if(!!'false') { alert('its true')}` still alerts `'true'`.

Comment: To add to Daniel's comment, non-empty strings in javascript are always considered "truthy." A null or empty-string will be considered "falsy" when casting. Perhaps you meant to write `if(!!true) { alert('it is true')}` ?

Comment: you'r right!, sorry the poor/short answer.. :)
Daniel's answer is more complete